# can not query columns with chinese characters in hive

Tags: hive

i have a table in have with columns including chinese characters,
[image]
when i try to query this field "last_name", like: find records starting with "潘", i query it as below:
[image]
how to deal with such a problem, so that i can query chinese content ?

Comment: Depending on the database prefixing the search term with 'E' for Postgres 'N' for sql server should return the right results. Check these out for more info https://help.scribesoft.com/scribeinsight/en/Subsystems/Insight/configsource/sqlqueries/creating_a_sql_query_with_unicode_data.htm

Comment: it is hive, i try to add N or E, it doesn't work,

Comment: Could you please provide more details, like the version of Hive you are using? I tried to reproduce your issue, but on my setup with Hive 2.0.1, everything works fine. Maybe you should check the `locale` on your client and on the server.

Comment: i used to use cloudera 5.8, it doesn't work, but i change to use new version of 5.12, it works now, thanks